# Shortcut missing from desktop but is in desktop folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, shortcuts, desktop

I have a couple shortcuts that are not visible on desktop but if i go to Computer > desktop I can see them in the folder.

It is visible when I plug in a different laptop to my monitor, so multiple monitors seems to be causing the problem.

How to bring hidden shortcuts back onto my desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right click desktop
2. View
3. Auto arrange icons

They will now all re-appear.

Repeat steps to turn off auto arrange and then you can again manually move your icons wherever you like.

Answer (score 1):

This sometimes happens on Windows 10 with multiple monitors enabled, especially where the form factor (width/height) of the monitors are different.

The following solution has worked for me every time.

- Open Explorer so you can see the desktop in the background
- Navigate to the Desktop folder, `C:\Users\[USER]\Desktop`
- Find the shortcut that is not displayed on the desktop
- `Cut` and `Paste` the shortcut to a different location, say `C:\Tmp`
- Navigate to where you moved the shortcut, `C:\Tmp`
- Drag the shortcut to the desktop and release
- Move the icon/shortcut to your desired location

Looks like a Windows 10 bug (mine is version 1903 Build 18362.900).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently. After the most recent Windows 10 update (version 21H2) my desktop shortcuts vanished but I could still see them in my desktop folder. After some digging I found that somehow my desktop icons got hidden. What I did was:

- Right Click --> View
- Show desktop icons

And all my icons reappeared on my desktop GUI. Hope this helps